Make clickable terms in AndroidView (WebView) - Jetpack Compose
I want to click on terms in a android web view to do an action, like showing a toast that contains that term that we already clicked.
`class WebAppInterface(private val context: Context) {
    @JavascriptInterface
    fun showToast(toastMessage: String) {
        Toast.makeText(context, toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Composable
fun HtmlText(htmlContent: String) {
val rightAlignedHtmlContent = """
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                text-align: right;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        $htmlContent
    </body>
    </html>
    """.trimIndent()
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(color = Color.Transparent, shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
            .border(width = 1.dp, color = Color.Transparent),
    ) {

        AndroidView(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize().padding(8.dp)
                .background(color = Color.Transparent, shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
                .border(width = 1.dp, color = Color.Transparent),
            factory = { context ->
                WebView(context).apply {
                    webViewClient = WebViewClient()
                    settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                    addJavascriptInterface(WebAppInterface(context), "Android")
                    loadDataWithBaseURL(null, rightAlignedHtmlContent, "text/html", "UTF-8",       null)
               }
           },
              update = { webView ->
               webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, rightAlignedHtmlContent, "text/html", "UTF-8", null)
            }
        )
    }
}`

This is my jetpack compose code.
the click on each term in AndroidView is not working.
